# Oracle APEX - Find all pages utilizing specific LOV

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I want to find out if a specific LOV has been used by any pages in my application. I assume this can be done by querying APEX express views. I found a view containing LOV data - APEX_APPLICATION_LOVS but that does not help me get the list of pages utilizing the LOV. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is via the APEX Builder tool:
[image]

As that shows, there are 3 places they can be used:

- page items
- report columns
- interactive reports

(though I would expect interactive grids to be there too, and perhaps facets too).

Another way to to search APEX_DICTIONARY for likely columns e.g.

```
select * from apex_dictionary
where column_name like '%NAMED_LOV%';
```

That returns:

- APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IR_COL
- APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS
- APEX_APPL_PAGE_FACETS

I don't have the definitive list, but I hope that helps.